# Applying filter GridFS MongoDb C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, filtering, gridfs

I am trying to filter my data based on the two factors. The first factor is the docID(object Id) and the second factor is DocType which is stored as metadata. The sample code I am pasting.I am also attaching the sample DB how it looks[image] like.

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteDocument([FromRoute] int docType, [FromRoute] string docId)
        {
            try
            {
                var filter = Builders<GridFSFileInfo>.Filter.And(
    Builders<GridFSFileInfo>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Metadata.GetValue("DocType"), docType),
    Builders<GridFSFileInfo>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id.ToString(), docId));
                
                using (var cursor = await Bucket.FindAsync(filter))
                {
                    var fileInfos = (await cursor.ToListAsync());
                    foreach (GridFSFileInfo fileInfo in fileInfos)
                    {

                        foreach (BsonElement bsonE in fileInfo.Metadata.ToList())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(fileInfo.Filename);
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
```

But I am not getting the correct result it giving me errors. Can anyone please point out what I am doing wrong or how to write filters based on metadata information.

Comment: Are you trying to use `.Eq(x => x.Id.ToString(), docId)` to match on the `_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like they're a few problems with the above code. The MongoDB Driver is struggling with converting these expressions into a MongoDB Query.

```cs
.Eq(x => x.Metadata.GetValue("DocType"), docType)
```

```cs
.Eq(x => x.Id.ToString(), docId)
```

This is because you need to use the indexer to accessing fields of the metadata, also you'll need to change docId into the correct type before comparing it against the Id field.

Try the following filter out.

```cs
var docType = 1;
var docId = ObjectId.Parse("5f3ce002796ba13443aa4bc5");

var filter = 
    Builders<GridFSFileInfo<ObjectId>>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Metadata["DocType"], docType)
    & Builders<GridFSFileInfo<ObjectId>>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, docId);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I figured out what was going wrong. You correctly pointed out the things. So, I marked this as resolved.